# Vba: Select Multiple rows based on Text

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list made up of 4 columns and undetermined rows. I am trying to collect only Col B and C where Col B has words Jackpot and copy them in order to a new sheet. I have gotten the list to sort, but using UsedRange, copies all the rows. How do I only copy over B and C?

```
Range("A1").Activate
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Jackpot"

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
```

---

```
Col A | Col B |      Col C | Col D
1       Stuff          1       1
1       MoreStuff      2       1
1       Jackpot        3       1
1       Jackpot        4       1
1       SomeStuff      5       1
1       Jackpot        6       1
```

Comment: Go to macro recorder and turn it on. Select all. Add filter. In Filter filter column B using your word. Select result. Paste result to new sheet. Turn off macro recorder. Check out the vba macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First cut, although I do have some questions:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
ws.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Jackpot"
ws.Range("B2:C2", Range("B2:C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DestinationSheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

1) Will this be happening in the same sheet every time (ex. `Worksheets("Results")`)?
2) Do you want to include the header row?  If so, change the `.Copy` line to `B1:C1` in both instances.  The current implementation just takes the filtered content without the header.

Obviously you'll need to change the worksheet names to match your implementation.

Answer (score 3):

After you filter it, you can select the range B:C and then copy to your destination. I updated your code to show you an example. Also, you don't always need to "Select" anything with VBA (it's very rare to *have* to do that).

Hope this helps

```
Option Explicit

Sub doIt()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    sh.Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Jackpot"

    ' make sure results were returned from the filter
    If (sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Address <> "$A$1") Then

        Dim newSh As Worksheet
        Set newSh = Sheets.Add

        sh.Range("B:C").Copy newSh.Range("A1")

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way of doing it that does not rely on the auto-filter. Not sure speed-wise which is quicker, but I wanted to offer up another solution to your problem.

```
Sub CopyJackpot()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

j = 1
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    If InStr(Range("B" & i).Value, "Jackpot") Then
       Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox j - 1 & " row(s) copied to Sheet2."

End Sub
```